# "Resource should pre-exist" error when adding Advanced Filters to EventGrid Subscription

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-eventgrid

Why is this happening and how do I get around it?

**Issue:**

- Existing infrastructure
- Python Azure Function triggered by EventGrid
- EventGrid messages created upon BlobUpload to a Storage Account
- When creating Advanced Filters for the EventGrid Subscription, I receive the error:

```
Deploying Event Subscription: my-eventgrid-sub-name
Deployment has failed with the following error: 
{
    code:"Endpoint validation",
    message:"Destination azure endpoint not found,
    Resource details: resourceId:/subscriptions/<redacted>/resourceGroups/<redacted>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/myFunctionAppName/functions/myFunctionName. 
    Resource should pre-exist before attempting this operation,
    Activity id:7e9c4817-5bbd-4772-a7b0-a4dbc70dbf04, 
    timestamp: 10/24/2020 7:01:39 PM (UTC)."
}
```

[image]

Of course `myFucnctionName` exists. Its existed and been operational for weeks now. It seems like EventGrid can't "see" the Function.

**EDIT 1:**

- Updated the image above. I should have seen that the app was stopped. I guess this effects the ability to add EventGrid filters.
- Started the app, all good now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As the error message - `Resource should pre-exist before attempting this operation` says, there are two potential causes to this error:*

- You have not created Event Grid Trigger function app, which you are pointing in this subscription.
- The artifact of function app is not correctly deployed and function app is not present.

Comment: Actually had this pop up again yesterday for another reason: The `AzureWebJobsStorage` property of `local.settings.json` was set incorrectly. This disallowed me from editing the EventGrid advanced filter. Once corrected, it saved without issue.